# Compare two colums in two sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want a faster way to compare two ranges in two worksheets with each worksheet having about 15000 rows.

If they match, print "Nothing Changed" in column J else print "Something Changed" in column K.

This code doesn't work when sheet1 and sheet2 are not in order.

```
Dim array_a, array_b, array_c, array_d As Variant
Dim lastrow_a, lastrow_b As Integer
Dim i, ii As Integer

lastrow_a = Worksheets("Current_Month").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow_b = Worksheets("Last_Month").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

array_a = Worksheets("Current_Month").Range("F2:F" & lastrow_a).Value
array_b = Worksheets("Last_Month").Range("F2:F" & lastrow_b).Value

ReDim array_c(1 To WorksheetFunction.Max(UBound(array_a, 1), UBound(array_b, 1)), 1)
ReDim array_d(1 To WorksheetFunction.Max(UBound(array_a, 1), UBound(array_b, 1)), 1)

For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.Min(UBound(array_a, 1), UBound(array_b, 1))
    If array_a(i, 1) = array_b(i, 1) Then
        array_c(i, 0) = "Nothing Changed"
    Else: array_d(i, 0) = "Something Changed"
    End If
Next i

Worksheets("Current_Month").Range("J2:J" & UBound(array_c, 1)).Value = array_c
Worksheets("Current_Month").Range("K2:K" & UBound(array_c, 1)).Value = array_d

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a formula if you want this faster.  Looks like you're only comparing a 1 to 1 cell, so something like this might work:  `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A1,0)),"Changed","No Change")`

Comment: Additionally, you need to qualify ALL ranges, e.g., `Worksheets("Current_Month").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` is missing a `Worksheets("Current_Month").` before the `Rows.Count`, meaning that rows.count is counting the ACTIVESHEET.  You can use a `With` statement to make it a little easier

Comment: Thank You for your response the thing is, what is in A1 of sheet2 could be in A20 of sheet 1 i want to look through it sheet1 and see if it exist.

Comment: Is your goal to only verify that a specific cell's value has not changed (single cell references) or that a cell's value is found within a range (`match()` over a range)?

Comment: yes trying to verify that a cell's value is found with in a range

Comment: Are the values in the column `F` unique?

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer after reading in comments  from comments:

Then you just want a `match()` formula and shouldn't need VBA, with some error handling, e.g.:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"Changed","No Change")
```

If `match()` doesn't find a match, it will throw an error, which using `iserror()` to determine if true or false in the `if-statement` lets you say then when it's found (no error = false) it writes "no change", and when nothing is found in the range (error = true) then it says "changed".

The only change from the first comment is that I gave you a range, `sheets2!A:A`, rather than a 1:1 cell comparison.